# What's the proper way of collecting all the data from API with paging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, api, loopbackjs

I'm trying to collect all the data at once from this specific API: https://docs.nuapay.com/v1/#list-mandates using JavaScript, node.js and Loopback framework.

However they are using paging and each page with response for mandates include only 20 results, and our API include over 700 pages.

In this case I'll have to do over 700 API calls to build the total result.

What's the best practice to recover results for all the pages without slowing down the process ?

Typical response for this API will be:

```
{
  "uri" : "/schemes/46pkx7o9n5/mandates",
  "data" : [ {
    "id" : "46pkxn8e9n",
    "uri" : "/schemes/8g3o2yyk2w/mandates/46pkxn8e9n",
    "mandateId" : "BEL000049995012C",
    "debtorName" : "Debtor Name",
    "debtorIBAN" : "GB94SELN00999976543215",
    "debtorMobileNumber" : "0360321312312",
    "mandateStatus" : "PENDING",
    "creationDate" : "2015-07-21"
  }, {
    "id" : "nx9kndaejm",
    "uri" : "/schemes/8g3o2yyk2w/mandates/nx9kndaejm",
    "mandateId" : "BEL000049995012S",
    "debtorName" : "Debtor Name",
    "debtorIBAN" : "GB94SELN00999976543215",
    "debtorMobileNumber" : "0360321312312",
    "mandateStatus" : "ACTIVE",
    "creationDate" : "2015-07-21"
  }, {
    "id" : "vw7kj9gey5",
    "uri" : "/schemes/8g3o2yyk2w/mandates/vw7kj9gey5",
    "mandateId" : "BEL000049995012X",
    "debtorName" : "Debtor Name",
    "debtorIBAN" : "GB94SELN00999976543215",
    "debtorMobileNumber" : "0360321312312",
    "mandateStatus" : "ACTIVE",
    "creationDate" : "2015-07-21"
  } ],
  "page" : {
    "pageNumber" : 1,
    "pageSize" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 3,
    "totalPages" : 1
  },
  "sort" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: At 20 items per page over 700 pages it's never going to be fast to work with all the data. However an API like that normally has searching/filtering features so you should never need to download the entire dataset. That's the point of paging. If, for whatever reason, you do need all the data then you'll need to request the third-party API provider to make a change to allow you to retrieve it, however that's unlikely to happen.

Comment: you can pass it a different pageSize: https://docs.nuapay.com/v1/#pagination

Comment: you can create many http requests in parallel -  the OS will block until the have results.  Your problem will be how you merge the results back together, as you cant guarantee ordering of responses.  The may also be rate limiting on the server you are contacting

Comment: To add to @developer 's comment - you could use an ajax queue to ensure the results are in order (and that you don't overload the server and get blocked!)  but it still won't be quick (so ok for a one-off "export")